# Did Musa(AS) used to pray salaat?

Tags: salat, prophet-musa

I wanted to know about Musa's (AS) prayers because one of my friend says that Mohammed(SAW) brought namaz and the earlier messengers did not.

But I heard that Musa(AS) used to pray 3 times in a day.I don't have any resources to know about this, that's why I am asking you people, to help me and elaborate about the Salat as prayed by Musa(AS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has any bearing on how Moses originally prayed, currently [Judaism has 3 daily prayers](https://www.chabad.org/search/keyword_cdo/kid/8604/jewish/Three-Daily-Prayers-The.htm):

[Sacharid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYxWcRCCNBw), [the morning prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shacharit)

[Mincha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mincha), the afternoon prayer

[Maariv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maariv), (Sounds like the Muslim 'Maghrib'), the evening prayer

When we compare these to the 5 salahs of the daily Muslim worship, the most striking difference is that the Jews lay flat on the ground with forehead to the ground in their Sujud (prostration) in the Jewish worship as demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aHWASyMjwg) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0r4953BESo&t=979s).

The Jews bend down for what appears similar to the Muslim Ruku, demonstrated also [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XgFA5UonqyU), but  they conclude their prayer by performing selawat to both sides while they are in ruku position whereas Muslims conclude with selawat kneeled in the sitting position.

I believe the Sujud is the most important part or climax of the Muslim Salat.  I could not find references to the Sujud in the Old Testament but in the New Testament, Jesus (Isa ibn Maryam) is mentioned putting his forehead on the ground in the gospels. The complete Muslim salah was presented to Muhammed pbuh when he went up on Miraj (the night ascension).  Originally the qibla was toward Jerusalem, but some time later switched to Mecca.

Answer (score 6):

Yes he did. This is proven in the Quran:

> وأوحينا إلى موسى وأخيه أن تبوآ لقومكما بمصر بيوتا واجعلوا بيوتكم قبلة **وأقيموا الصلاة** وبشر المؤمنين
>
> And We inspired to Moses and his brother, "Settle your people in Egypt in houses and make your houses [facing the] qiblah and **establish prayer** and give good tidings to the believers."
>
> <sup>— [Quran 10:87](https://quran.com/10/87)</sup>